# unable to pass environment variables to unicorn with foreman/upstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, foreman

I'm using foreman and upstart to start/stop my unicorn processes.

I use foreman to pass variables in the .env file to the rails app.

However, my environment variables are not being passed to the unicorn process.

I will be happy to post whatever config files are needed (I didn't want a wall of text).

for example: 
Procfile:

`web: foreman start 'unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb'`

which is then translated into the upstart as:

```
start on starting appname-web
stop on stopping appname-web
respawn

env PORT=5000
env GMAPS_KEY='GMAPS KEY'
env SECRET_KEY_BASE='THE SECRET'

setuid appname

chdir /srv/appname

exec foreman start 'unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb'
```

My setup might seem dated (because it is) and I am happy to hear alternatives.

Not hosted on Heroku in case this helps

Comment: Where and how are you trying to access the env vars?

Comment: i have a .env file were I store them. 'foreman export' puts them in that upstart file

Comment: so, it seems like the .yml env config parsing isn't working but it works fine in templates. Secret doesn't get passed but the google maps key does. Strange.